# Javascript Object not defined after being created in a function

Tags: javascript, function, object

I can't seem to return an object from a function, the console.log inside the function prints out the property values fine but once outside the function I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: firstOn is not defined"

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
myElement = document.getElementById("testButton");

function Server(name,tables,startTime) {
    this.name = name;
    this.tables = tables;
    this.startTime = startTime;
}


document.forms.server1.button.onclick = function() {
    var name = document.forms.server1.servername.value;
    var tables = document.forms.server1.servertables.value;
    var startTime = document.forms.server1.servertime.value;

    var firstOn = new Server(name,tables,startTime);

    document.forms.server1.button.innerHTML = "Saved!";

    console.log(firstOn.name);
    console.log(firstOn.tables);
    console.log(firstOn.startTime);

    return firstOn;

};

myElement.onclick = function() {
    console.log(firstOn.name);
    console.log(firstOn.tables);
    console.log(firstOn.startTime);

};
```

Comment: It's only available in the scope it was declared in. Move the declaration out of the function. You might also need to get rid of `var`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`firstOn` is an object that was created and returned from the `document.forms.server1.button.onclick` event handler.  The return value from that event handler went into the system (that's where event handlers return to) and was never stored anywhere so it was cleaned up by the system with garbage collection.

Meanwhile, your `myElement.onclick` event handler does NOT have access to the `firstOn` object because it wasn't saved anywhere that `myElement.onclick` can reach.

If you want `firstOn` to be usable after the `document.forms.server1.button.onclick` event handler, you have to save it somewhere that the second click handler can each.  That could be in a global variable or it could be a property of some other object that is globally accessible.  As your code is written right now, the `firstOn` object is created, but never stored anywhere so it is happily cleaned up by the garbage collector and is not reachable by other code.

Answer (score 3):

That firstOn object was created in the local function scope.  It will not be available globally in the second function.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the appropriate solution to my problem.

```
myElement = document.getElementById("testButton");

function Server(name,tables,startTime) {
    this.name = name;
    this.tables = tables;
    this.startTime = startTime;
}

var firstOn = new Server();

document.forms.server1.button.onclick = function() {
    firstOn.name = document.forms.server1.servername.value;
    firstOn.tables = document.forms.server1.servertables.value;
    firstOn.startTime = document.forms.server1.servertime.value;

    document.forms.server1.button.innerHTML = "Saved!";

    console.log(firstOn.name);
    console.log(firstOn.tables);
    console.log(firstOn.startTime);

    return firstOn;

};

myElement.onclick = function() {
   console.log(firstOn.name);
   console.log(firstOn.tables);
   console.log(firstOn.startTime);
};
```

Comment: There's no point in returning `firstOn` from `document.forms.server1.button.onclick`.  That accomplishes nothing.  This solution (storing it in a global variable), is consistent with what I explained in my answer and is one of the options for fixing your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstOn = new winMain.Server(name,tables,startTime);
```

Comment: Try to give an explanation as well :-)